# Concatenate several fields in JSON within Pig script

Tags: json, apache-pig

I'm all over Stack looking for a solution for this, can't seem to arrive at anything close.

I have a custom compression UDF and would like to output a `JSON` key-value format from Pig using `JsonStorage()`. The twist is, I'd like to concatenate several fields into `JSON`, and then compress them using my UDF, prior to output using `JsonStorage()`.

The final output ideally would look something like:

```
{ '00001' : '<COMPRESSED BYTES>' }
{ '00002' : '<OTHER COMPRESSED BYTES>' }
```

Where the value of the compressed bytes would decompress to

```
{ 'id': '00001', 'v1': 'value1', ... , 'vN': 'valueN' }
{ 'id': '00002', 'v1': 'othervalue1', ... , 'vN': 'othervalueN' }
```

...You get the idea.

Is there a built-in or PiggyBank way to encode `JSON` inside a Pig script?

```
register $MY_COMPRESS_UDF_JAR;
define compress my.compress.udf(args);

A = load 'example.csv' using PigStorage(',') as $fields;
B = foreach A generate encode_json($subset_of_fields) as jsonstr;

J = foreach B generate id, compress(jsonstr);

store J into 'example.json' using JsonStorage();
```

Where `encode_json` is some way of turning multiple fields into a single `JSON` string.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: did you try python method string.encode()

Answer (score 0):

OK, there seems to be a dearth of solutions in native Pig. I decided to create another UDF to perform this simple encoding. It's rough, but it works:

```
public class JsonEncode extends EvalFunc<String> {

    /*
     *  Pig provides a tuple of fields to encode, 
     *  with first field being a comma-separated
     *  list of field names
     */

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        // Build JSON object, return as string
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        String fieldlist = (String) input.get(0);
        String[] fields = fieldlist.split(",", -1);

        for(int i = 1; i <= fields.length; i++) {
            js.put(fields[i-1], input.get(i));       
        }

        return js.toString();
    };

}
```

In Pig:

```
define compress my.compress.udf(args);
define json_encode my.encode.udf();    

A = load 'example.csv' using PigStorage(',') as $fields;

-- NB: first argument is quoted list of field names
B = foreach A generate json_encode('$subset_of_fields', $subset_of_fields) as jsonstr;

J = foreach B generate id, compress(jsonstr);
store J into 'example.out.csv' using PigStorage(',');
```

And output appears as:

```
00001,<compressed bytes>
00002,<other compressed bytes>
```